# how to clear text from a text widget from a class method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to OOPs. I wrote following code where `delText` method clears text field when clicked on a text widget. I called `delText` method by binding it with a `<FocusIn>` but I am getting error

```
AttributeError: 'GuiAndFileMethods' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

and further I want to read text in some other method. I know that my method is not recognizing the widget on which delete to be done. so how to do it ?

**my code**

```
from tkinter import *  
class GuiAndFileMethods(Frame):
    def delText(obj,event=None):
       obj.delete("1.0", END)   
z = GuiAndFileMethods()
root = Tk()
fileName = Text(root, height = 1, width = 57, wrap = None )
fileName.insert(INSERT, "Filename")
fileName.grid(row = 1, column = 0,columnspan = 5, padx = (10,50),sticky = W)
fileName.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda x: z.delText(fileName))

replacementNum = Text(root, height = 1, width = 18, wrap = None )
replacementNum.insert(INSERT, "No Of Replacements")
replacementNum.grid(row = 1, column = 6,columnspan = 1,sticky = E)
replacementNum.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda x: z.delText(replacementNum))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can change `def delText(obj, event=None)` to `def delText(self, obj, event=None)`.  Also why `GuiAndFileMethods` inherited from `Frame`?  Your code will create two instances of `Tk()`.  `GuiAndFileMethods` should not inherit from `Frame`.

Comment: @acw1668 I saw it in some answer on this site they inherit class from `tk.Frame` so i tried with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either define your function as a static function:

```
class GuiAndFileMethods(Frame):
    @staticmethod
    def delText(obj,event=None):
       obj.delete("1.0", END)
```

Or pass `self` as the first argument of the function:

```
class GuiAndFileMethods(Frame):
    def delText(self, obj,event=None):
       obj.delete("1.0", END)
```

In this case, since you are not using any attribute of the class that you are defining, I suggest to go with the first approach.

Comment: the `@staticmethod` works but `self` doesnt work cuz I may be Textbox widget is not part of my class

Comment: That's strange... I tried your code with `self` and it was working too... Remember that you have to call `deltText` the same way, the only change is adding `self` in the definition of the function.

Comment: yeah understood and it worked to. when you asked me to use self i changed `obj.delete("1.0",END)` to `self.delete("1.0",END)` and this is because the first argument to a class method is self and i was asking code to call `GuiAndFileMethods.delText()` and now i change it to `obj.delete("1.0", END)` thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

When you define a method like that, Python will automatically insert the instance of the class as the first argument. This is called `self` by convention, but it doesn't have to be. So `obj` there is actually the instance of `GuiAndFileMethods` class, NOT the object you passed in. The object you pass in will be the second argument of:

```py
def delText(instanceof_GuiAndFileMethods, obj, event=None):
    obj.delete("1.0", END)
```

So, how you define it and how you call it are slightly different. You would call it like this:

```py
instanceof_GuiAndFileMethods.delText(obj, event)
```

That object you call the method on gets inserted as the first argument (again, usually `self`).